# Running a Ruby on Rails app from GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

Im new to github..  I have register my name there, I'm not a rails developer, but i want to learn Ruby on Rails.

Have someone any idea about its basic tutorials for creating Ruby on Rails applications, execute them etc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

GitHub isn't a web host, it's a version control repository. You put your source code there to share with others (either the general public, for open source stuff, or members of your team).

For getting going with Rails, I'd suggest [Heroku](http://heroku.com). It uses git as the way to get your app running on their servers, which is ridiculously simple. It's also free to get going, you only need to pay if your web traffic gets too big or if you want to use advanced features.

When I was learning Rails, the two sources that helped the most were the [Pragmatic Programmers  book Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) book and Ryan Bates' excellent [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) site.

Comment: Github does have some hosting features, so the question isn't completely off the wall.   https://pages.github.com/

Comment: GitHub doesn't host Ruby on Rails applications, which is what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 7):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html will help you i think.You can start reading from here.

If you want to run a project from git the you have to do the following

```
->git clone git@github.com:Project/project.git [A public project of github]
->cd project
->bundle install
->rake db:migrate
->rails server
```

but before this you have to set up your ruby on rails environment.Rubymine is one of the best IDE for ROR development.

Best of Luck !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check out some tutorials from here - http://www.rubyonrailstutorials.com/ 
Almost all of them include describing work with git and github.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you should check the documentation from the framework's page at http://rubyonrails.org

A quick guide to run the server locally:

For rails application prior to version 3.0 you should run:

```
ruby script/server
```

For newer applications you should run:

```
rails server
```

But there are probably a lot of other topics to review first (depending on the application):

- Dependency installation
- Database configuration
- Custom initializers
- Etc...

If the application doesn't have a decent Readme file or any other documentation you should probably need to ask the application author for some help.

Hope that help, don't give up, there are a lot of new things to learn but I think the effort worth it. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

After cloning
1.install rbenv or rvm for managing and installing ruby
In terminal(your project root)
2. sudo gem install bundler
3. bundle install
3. rails s

Comment: The questioner states both 'New' to github, and 'New' to Ruby on Rails. I'm sorry to say your answer needs a lot of simplification and clarification to be useful to someone new to both environments.